# "No parameter named table" in SQLModel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic, sqlmodel

The SQLModel [documentation](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/insert/) tells us that we should define a mapped table as follows:

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

Since the latest version 0.0.14, pylance is giving me the warning: "No parameter called 'table'".

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this for now? The code still runs if I use `# type: ignore`, but this seems non-ideal in the long run.

Comment: don't bother `pylancer` but run code to see if it can work.

Comment: in question (not in comments) you could add link to `SQLModel documentation` .

Comment: Documentation added. Code does still run (I updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading sqlmodel to 0.0.13 solved this for me. I'd say it's a bug in 0.0.14.

Comment: Downgrading would definitely work, but I need 0.0.14  for its pydantic 2.0 support, so this is not an option for me.

Comment: https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues